# Trigger event listener

Tags: jquery

I am currently making a website with the use of simpleCart(js)(open jQuery Shopping Cart).

In html this fires the `event` to empty the shopping cart:

```
<a class="simpleCart_empty" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

I would like to combine this event with a few other action so I try to fire it on my commend without actually clicking on the link.

The source has this:

```
 me.addEventToArray( getElementsByClassName('simpleCart_empty') , simpleCart.empty , "click" );
```

Does anyone no how to trigger it in jQuery? Or how to find how to do that?
A regular:

```
 $(".simpleCart_empty").trigger('click');
```

doesn't work, and seems like a wrong workaround.

The code:

```
$(simpleCart.empty).trigger('click');
```

Does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the bind() function of jQuery

```
 $('.simpleCart_empty').bind('click', function() {
     alert('Should empty cart');
 });
```

Just replace the alert with the actions you want to execute

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
$(".simpleCart_empty").click();
```

Comment: That din't work but just found out $(simpleCart.empty).trigger('click'); does.